# Addition of $X^*$ is continuous w.r.t. Weak Topology $\sigma(X^*, X)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I showed that the addition on $X^*$ is continuous w.r.t. Weak Topology $\sigma(X^*, X)$. Since I'm a newbie in this field, would you please check my proof and answer that my proof is correct or not?

Let $X$ be normed space and for $\varphi \in X^*$, $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in X$, $\epsilon >0$, define $V(\varphi; x_1, \cdots, x_n; \epsilon) = \{\psi\in X^*: \forall i=1,\cdots,n, |\psi(x_i) - \varphi(x_i)| < \epsilon\}.$
Let $\sigma(X^*, X)$ be a topology generated by $\{V(\varphi; x_1, \cdots, x_n; \epsilon): x_1, \cdots, x_n \in X, \epsilon >0, \varphi \in X^*\}.$

Now I defined $\xi: X^* \times X^* \ni (\varphi_1, \varphi_2) \mapsto \varphi_1 + \varphi_2 \in  X^*$. For $x_1, \cdots, x_n \in X$, $\epsilon >0$,  I showed that $$
V(\varphi_1; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon / 2) \times V(\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon / 2) \subset \xi^{-1}(V(\varphi_1+\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon ) ), 
$$
since if $(\psi, \phi)\in (left)$, we have
$$
|(\psi+\phi)(x_i) - (\varphi_1 + \varphi_2)(x_i)| \le |(\psi - \varphi_1)(x_i)| + |(\phi - \varphi_2)(x_i)| < \epsilon / 2 + \epsilon/ 2.
$$
I think this proof shows that the continuity. Would you please check my proof and answer that my proof is correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct, because the general case follows from what you have shown.  Given *any* open neighborhood $W$ of $\varphi_1+\varphi_2$, we know there exists some $ V(\varphi_1+\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon )$ such that 
$$\varphi_1+\varphi_2\in V(\varphi_1+\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon )\subset W.$$
Then we have
$$ V(\varphi_1; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon / 2)+V(\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon / 2)\subset V(\varphi_1+\varphi_2; x_1, \cdots, x_n ; \epsilon )\subset W $$